# JavaFX: How can I rotate a 3D-box 90-degrees with the keyboard, and then save and load the rotation using JSON?

Tags: java, json, javafx, rotation, mesh

I have a 'javafx.scene.shape.Box' with a 'javafx.scene.shape.MeshView' shown at it's coordinates.

I want to rotate this box 90-degrees using the keyboard (perhaps WASDQE, WS, QE and AD for the different axises). I also want to save the box-rotation to JSON and then be able to set that rotation again.

What I've tried (the box- and meshview-properties are bound):

```
box.setRotate(box.getRotate + angle); // angle being +-90 and reset on > 360 or < -360
box.setRotationAxis(Rotate.X_AXIS); // Axis depending on key pressed
```

This approach works for the current axis, and it works to save and load using JSON since I can set/get this value. However, with this, it seems I can not rotate all the angles, because when I change rotation-axis it forgets the previous rotation and starts from the 'default'/'starting'-rotation.

I've also tried doing it like below:

```
this.setRotationAxis(this.getRotationAxis().normalize().add(Rotate.X_AXIS));
```

This approach results with the box rotating on multiple axis, in other words, it seems to remember previous axises, but it does not rotate the axis I just added by the angle given. The box ends up tilted.

The last thing I've tried was to add the rotation as a transform:

```
this.getTransforms().add(new Rotate(angle, Rotate.X_AXIS));

(
also tried this with some code I found that did this with inverseDeltaTransform (where node being the box):

private void addRotate(Node node, Point3D rotationAxis, double angle) {
      ObservableList<Transform> transforms = node.getTransforms();
      try {
          for (Transform t : transforms) {
             rotationAxis = t.inverseDeltaTransform(rotationAxis);
          }
      } catch (NonInvertibleTransformException ex) {
          throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
      }
          transforms.add(new Rotate(angle, rotationAxis));
     }

)
```

This approach, however, leaves me with two problems.

Problem 1:
If i render the box, it rotates just fine, but if I render the meshview, it seems to rotate around a pivot rather then to rotate on the spot.

Problem 2:
If i add the rotation through transforms, how would I save the current rotation to JSON and then apply it again when I load it?
box.getRotationAxis() and box.getRotate() will now just show the default-values as if the box is never rotated and box.getTransforms() does not seem to make this easy.

Another question about the transforms:
The list of transforms is building up with every rotation, would I need to clear this list to avoid memory-issues and would clearing the list affect the current rotation?

Comment: For the second part, rather than apply the transform on key press, you should add it to an ObservableList of POJO containing the angle and axis. This list is easily serializable to a JSON, and you can add a listener to it so the transform is built from the POJO and applied when an element is added.

Comment: @Balderk Smart! That would allow me to save and load the rotation relatively easy. The backside would be the memory-consumption, if I rotate multiple boxes lots of times.. But it's a start, thank you!

Comment: You're right, I didn't consider that... There's actually a finite number of possible positions for your shape, but I haven't done that kind of maths in a while so can't really help. Have you checked https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/19259/how-should-i-model-exact-90-degree-rotations-in-3d , this seems relevant

Comment: @Balderk That looks very relevant, I'll look into it! Thank you again. :)